# Why am I getting this error in my navigation code in my ReactNative app?

Tags: react-native

I wrote the navigation code like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {Main} from './app/view/main';

export const App = () => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Main}
          options={{title: 'Welcome'}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

The environment is as below

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
  OS: macOS 13.3.1
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
  Memory: 87.95 MB / 8.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 20.5.1
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.19
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 9.8.0
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2023.08.14.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.11.3
    path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 22.4
      - iOS 16.4
      - macOS 13.3
      - tvOS 16.4
      - watchOS 9.4
  Android SDK:
    API Levels:
      - "28"
      - "29"
      - "30"
      - "31"
      - "33"
    Build Tools:
      - 30.0.3
      - 33.0.0
    System Images:
      - android-33 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      - android-33 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
    Android NDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996
  Xcode:
    version: 14.3.1/14E300c
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 20.0.2
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.4
    wanted: 0.72.4
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
```

The installed packages are as follows

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.24.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

I don't know why an error occurs when the navigation code is entered, how can I solve this problem?

After creating a project with npx react-native init projectName, I followed the navigation code in the manual, followed all items in the manual, and installed all necessary libraries, but the above error occurs

error code

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4 from /Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/weve/.: 

None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4/index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/weve/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:114:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/weve/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
    at /Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/weve/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:169:21
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (/Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/weve/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1045:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Server._explodedSourceMapForBundleOptions (/Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/weve/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:993:35)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Server._symbolicate (/Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/weve/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:945:26)
    at async Server._processRequest (/Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/weve/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:418:7)
 LOG  JavaScript logs will appear in your browser console
```

Are there hidden installation items that are not listed in the manual?

browser console error

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
reactConsoleErrorHandler @ ExceptionsManager.js:158
registerError @ LogBox.js:211
console.error @ LogBox.js:67
printWarning @ react-jsx-runtime.development.js:87
error @ react-jsx-runtime.development.js:61
jsxWithValidation @ react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1244
jsxWithValidationDynamic @ react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1301
renderApplication @ renderApplication.js:57
run @ AppRegistry.js:120
runApplication @ AppRegistry.js:214
__callFunction @ MessageQueue.js:428
(anonymous) @ MessageQueue.js:113
__guard @ MessageQueue.js:368
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:112
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:69
debuggerWorker.js:69 Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in weve(RootComponent)
reactConsoleErrorHandler @ ExceptionsManager.js:158
registerError @ LogBox.js:187
console.error @ LogBox.js:67
overrideMethod @ backend.js:13402
reportException @ ExceptionsManager.js:102
handleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:148
showErrorDialog @ ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:52
showErrorDialog @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13244
logCapturedError @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13251
update.callback @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13344
callCallback @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7968
commitUpdateQueue @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7989
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18602
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19806
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19792
commitLayoutEffects @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19775
commitRootImpl @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21745
commitRoot @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21593
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21051
flushSyncCallbacks @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:6262
flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:6241
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20460
updateContainer @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:23916
render @ ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:24678
renderElement @ RendererImplementation.js:35
renderApplication @ renderApplication.js:96
run @ AppRegistry.js:120
runApplication @ AppRegistry.js:214
__callFunction @ MessageQueue.js:428
(anonymous) @ MessageQueue.js:113
__guard @ MessageQueue.js:368
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:112
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:69
debuggerWorker.js:69 Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in weve(RootComponent)
reactConsoleErrorHandler @ ExceptionsManager.js:158
registerError @ LogBox.js:187
console.error @ LogBox.js:67
overrideMethod @ backend.js:13402
reportException @ ExceptionsManager.js:102
handleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:148
handleError @ setUpErrorHandling.js:24
reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:49
__guard @ MessageQueue.js:370
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:112
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:69
Show 10 more frames
Show less
debuggerWorker.js:69 Invariant Violation: Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in Chrome.

 Consider providing alternative methods to expose this method in debug mode, e.g. by exposing constants ahead-of-time.
    at invariant (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.weve&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2747:17)
    at MessageQueue.callNativeSyncHook (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.weve&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3103:54)
    at Object.nonPromiseMethodWrapper [as getConsolePatchSettings] (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.weve&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2858:68)
    at Object.getConsolePatchSettings (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.weve&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:57816:111)
    at initializeConsolePatchSettings (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.weve&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:56917:70)
    at initializeUsingCachedSettings (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.weve&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:56911:13)
    at _connectToDevTools (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.weve&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:57009:17)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.weve&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:57003:26
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.weve&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:34977:21
    at _callTimer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.weve&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:34888:9)
```

Comment: Everything given in [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) is enough to make it work. Try to clean and follow the setup steps again.

Comment: Install the package @react-native-community/cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the navigation seems fine to me however you can try clearing the cache and try running the app again.

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
npx react-native run-android
npx react-native run-ios
```

OR resetting the metro bundler

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Or you can Reinstall Dependencies: Try deleting the `node_modules` folder and your `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` file, then run `npm install` or `yarn install` again to reinstall your dependencies.

Comment: Even if I delete --reset-cache and the module folder and install again, the same symptom exists. I also added an error occurring in the browser console to the question, can you check it?